# For $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $y > 0$, we have ${1\over{\sqrt{y}}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x - t)e^{{-\pi t^2}\over{y}}dt \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

For $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $y > 0$, let$$f_y(x) := {1\over{\sqrt{y}}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x - t)e^{{-\pi t^2}\over{y}}dt.$$

- Do we have $f_y \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for every $ y > 0$?
- Do we have $\lim_{y \to 0} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x) - f_y(x)|\,dx = 0$?
- Does there exist $C > 0$ such that, for every $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$,$$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \sup_{y > 0} \left|f_y(x)\right| > \lambda\right\} \le {C\over\lambda} \int_\mathbb{R} \left|f(t)\right|\,dt?$$
- If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}$, then do we have that for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{y \to 0} f_y(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: This is a convlution of two $L^1$ function thus is also $L^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer all 4 questions by elementary means.

Write $T_y$ for the linear operator that maps $f\in L^1$ to $f_y.$

For the first question we have

$$\eqalignno{
\|T_y f\|_1&=\frac1{\sqrt y}\int_x\left|\int_t f(x-t)\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dt\right|dx\\
&\leq\frac1{\sqrt y}\int_x\int_t\left|f(x-t)\right|\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dtdx\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt y}\int_t\int_x|f(x-t)|dx\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dt&(*)\\
&=\|f\|_1\left(\frac1{\sqrt y}\int_t\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dt\right)\\
&=\|f\|_1.
}$$

where in (*) we use the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

The second question is the assertion that $\lim_{y\to0}T_yf=f$ in $L^1.$ This is easy to verify for $f$ the indicator function of an interval, and from there to finite linear combinations (block functions). But block functions are dense in $L^1,$ so if $f_b$ is a block function close to $f$ then

$$\eqalign{
\|T_yf-f\|_1&\leq\|T_y f-T_y f_b+T_y f_b-f_b+f_b-f\|_1\\
&\leq\|T_y(f-f_b)\|_1+\|T_yf_b-f_b\|_1+\|f_b-f\|_1\\
&\leq2\|f-f_b\|_1+\|T_yf_b-f_b\|_1
}$$

in view of the inequality in the answer to question 1.

Question 4 is about convergence almost everywhere, which follows from the stronger question 2 about convergence in $L^1.$

For question 3 note that the function

$$\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R:y\mapsto\frac1{\sqrt y}\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)$$

reaches its maximum when $y^2=\pi t^2,$ so we have

$$\sup_y\frac1{\sqrt y}\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)=\frac1{\pi^{1/4}\sqrt{|t|}}\exp(-\sqrt\pi|t|).$$

Let us denote the expression on the right hand side by $\phi(t),$ then $\phi$ is an integrable function.

Now we estimate

$$\eqalignno{
\int_x\sup_y|T_yf(x)|dx&\leq\int_x\sup_y\frac1{\sqrt y}\int_t|f(x-t)|\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dt\ dx\\
&\leq\int_x\int_t|f(x-t)|\sup_y\frac1{\sqrt y}\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dt\ dx\\
&=\int_t\int_x|f(x-t)|\sup_y\frac1{\sqrt y}\exp(-\frac{\pi t^2}y)dx\ dt&(*)\\
&=\|f\|_1\int_t\phi(t)dt
}$$

from which we deduce that $x\mapsto\sup_y|T_yf(x)|$ is an integrable function, and for any $\lambda>0$ the measure of

$$\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sup_y\left|f_y(x)\right|>\lambda\right\}$$

is bounded by

$$\frac{\|\phi\|_1}\lambda\|f\|_1.$$

Comment: For the first question, you should probably detail why you may permute the integrals.

Comment: I think part 3 follows even more straightforwardly from Chebyshev inequality and the result you proved in part 1. No?

Comment: @Alex M. Thanks, I will try to come up with something readable after I get some sleep :-)

Comment: @bartgol It looks like Chebyshev, but isn't the supremum getting in the way?

Comment: Uhm, I don't think so. Without the supremum it would be plain Chebyshev. But then, since the inequality would hold for every $y>0$, it would also hold for the supremum. No?

Comment: @bartgol If you leave out the supremum then the measure of the set is bounded by $(C/\lambda)\|f\|_1$ for some constant independent of $y,$ but the set itself still depends on $y.$ A priori the set *with* the supremum could have far larger measure than the supremum of the measures of the individual sets for different values of $y.$

Comment: I see. Not as easy as I thought. =)

Answer (score 1):

**Question (1)**

We shall use the theorem: $f, g \in L^1 (\Bbb R) \implies f * g \in L^1 (\Bbb R)$.

Choose $g_y (t) = \frac 1 {\sqrt y } \Bbb e ^{- \frac {\pi t^2} y}$ and verify that $\int \limits _{\Bbb R} |g_y| \ \Bbb d t = 1$, so the aforementioned theorem gives us that $f_y = f * g_y \in L^1 (\Bbb R)$.

**Question (2)**

We shall use the theorem: let $f, g \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ with $\int \limits _{\Bbb R} g \ \Bbb d t = 1$ and let $g_r (t) = \frac 1 r g(\frac t r)$; then $\| f * g_r - f \| _1 \to 0$.

Choose $g(t) = \Bbb e ^{- \pi t^2}$; choose $r = \sqrt y$ and note that $g_y (t) = \frac 1 {\sqrt y} g(\frac t {\sqrt y})$, so we may apply the aforementioned theorem to get that $\int \limits _{\Bbb R} |f_y(x) - f(x)| \Bbb d x = \| f * g_y - f \|_1 \to 0$.

The theorems can be found, for instance, in [lecture 4](http://www.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section4c_convolve.pdf) from the [course on Real Analysis](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/) by Cristopher Heil from Georgia Tech (theorem 1.12 for (1), and the bottom of p20 and top of p21 for (2)). Alternatively, you may want to take a look at the [Lecture 2](http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m526/Lecture2.pdf) of a [course](http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m526/) given by Hart Smith from the University of Washington (pages 2-6 for (1) and page 11 for (2)). In general, a search on the web for "convolution lp" or "convolution lp spaces" will return even more results.