# Prove: $\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\mathrm dx=0$

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

Suppose for  $\forall  [\alpha,\beta]\subset(-\infty,+\infty), f\in\mathcal{R}[\alpha,\beta]$, and $\exists ~p>0$, and  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f|^p\mathrm dx$ exists.Prove:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\mathrm dx=0$$
This question seems difficult for me to deal with, I think maybe I can use one continuous function to approach it or something like that, however, I do not know how to start. Since I haven't learn real analysis, so can you give me some primary solutions? Sincerely thanks for your help.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Since I haven't learn real analysis, so can you give me some primary solutions?

Comment: You might draw some inspiration from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568996/for-f-in-l1-mathbbr-and-y-0-we-have-1-over-sqrty-int-mathb).